# Laravel updating multiple hasMany / belongsToMany relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have inherited a project that has a a few CRUD forms ... On the create form we need to create entries for a `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` relationship. So basically what i have got is the following

```php
$movie = Movie::create($request->validated());

// Then to save the belongsToMany
foreach ($request['actors'] as $actor) {
  // do some data manipulation

  $actor = Actor::where('code', $actor->code)->first();

  $movie->actors()->attach($actor);
}

// Save the hasMany 
foreach ($request['comments'] as $comment) {
  // do some data manipulation

  $movie->comments()->create([
    'title' => $comment['title'],
    'body' => $comment['body'],
  ]);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing this, but it seems to work.

The problem I am having is that in the `edit` form, these actors / comments can be edited, added to or deleted and i am unsure of how to go about updating them. Is it possible to update them, or would it be better to delete the existing relationship data and re-add them?

I have never updated relationships, only added them so i am unsure how to even start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [laravel doc suggested](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) you can use `saveMany()` method for storing relationship instances.

```
// Save the hasMany 
foreach ($request['comments'] as $comment) {
  
  $comments[] = [
    new Comment([
      'title' => $comment['title'],
      'body' => $comment['body'],
    ]);  
  ];
}

!empty($comments) && $movie->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

For deletion and update you should define two routes, one for updating comment and one for deleting comment.

```
Route::patch('movie/{movie}/comment/{comment}',[MovieController::class,'updateComment']);
Route::delete('movie/{movie}/comment/{comment}',[MovieController::class,'deleteComment']);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that ... I have the update route in my resource controller but i am unsure on `how` to update relationships

Comment: Something like `$movie->comments()->where('id', $comment->id)->update(['title'=>'new title']);` ?

Comment: Im getting an error with the saveMany, Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given

Comment: @CodeSauce If you're saving only one comment, you should use `save()` and if you're opting to save many comments in one row, you should use `saveMany()`. You cannot pass an array of comments to `save()` method, as it expects one instance of Model class (which is Comment in this case).